# Clear page file using vba code

Tags: vba

I have a vba macro which runs a loop for about 200 iterations, using up the ram page file as it runs.

I need some kind of quick fix to clear the page file after every iteration. I know the best fix would be to clean up the code, but time is a constraint here.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of each loop iteration set any objects that will be re-created to `Nothing`.

This [article](http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=106) explains it in detail.

Comment: The Nothing tip is useful, but this function has too many cyclical references. Need to clean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this happen. It sounds like you have an ever-expanding array and may be running out of memory. I would stop it in a few places during the run, to see what is happening.

Comment: It is an array, but is cleared to nothing after each iteraration. The memory however, is not freed up.

Answer (score 0):

use Erase and array name. This erase all array contents.